# How can I convert CP1252 text file to Ascii for email export using Python?

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters

I have scraped several websites and consolidated the output into a single text file. When I then try to put that file into SMTPLib email chain I get an encoding error:

```
", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 156: invalid start byte
```

Here is my code. The text file does not have anything special in it from what I can tell:

```
import requests, os, smtplib, codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


homeworkResults = open('homeworkResults.txt','r', encoding= 'utf-8')
homeworkContent = homeworkResults.read()
#homeworkContent.encode()
homeworkResults.close()

print("attempting email...")

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('someemail@gmail.com','Password')
smtpObj.sendmail('someemail@gmail.com' , 'anotheremail@gmail.com','Subject: Kids Homework Update\n\n ' + homeworkContent) 
smtpObj.quit()
```

Comment: If the file is encoded as cp1252, why are you reading it as utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

It works after I added `codes.` before the `open` function.

This code also ignores decode errors by using the `ignore` argument: You can make `codecs.open()` ignore the decode error in your file by setting the `errors` argument to `ignore` or `replace`. It is set to `strict` by default.

```
import requests, os, smtplib, codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


homeworkResults = codecs.open('homeworkResults.txt','r', encoding= 'utf-8', errors='ignore')
homeworkContent = homeworkResults.read()
#homeworkContent.encode()
homeworkResults.close()

print("attempting email...")

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('someemail@gmail.com','Password')
smtpObj.sendmail('someemail@gmail.com' , 'anotheremail@gmail.com','Subject: Kids Homework Update\n\n ' + homeworkContent) 
smtpObj.quit()
```